# Cannot connect to a local mysql db with sqlalchemy on windows machine

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, database-connection, pymysql

I'm trying to connect to a local mysql DB on my windows machine using sqlalchemy. It works using pymysql, but not with sqlalchemy.

Code sqlalchemy:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://root:mypass@localhost/classicmodels')
engine.connect()
```

Gives error:

```
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1193, "Unknown system variable 'tx_isolation'")
```

Working code, using pymysql:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password = 'mypass',
                             db = 'classicmodels')

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('select * from customers')
mydata = cursor.fetchall()
mydata = pd.DataFrame(list(mydata))
mydata.head(5)
```

Comment: You're using the MySQLdb driver with SQLA. What if you use pymysql with it as well (`mysql+pymysql://...`)?

Comment: Thanks but that does not work either

Comment: What version of MySQL etc. are you using? Also please include the full traceback, not just the error message.

Answer (score 15):

I ran into a similar error involving tx_isolation.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1193, "Unknown system variable 'tx_isolation'")
```

This was due to using an old version of SQLAlchemy.

```
pip install --upgrade SQLAlchemy
```

I was running off v1.0.15, upgrading to v1.2.9 fixed the error for me. I am also using the `mysql+pymysql` connection setting as mentioned above.

Comment: I upgraded from 1.1.13 to 1.2.15 and had/fixed this error.

Answer (score 6):

What's your version of sqlalchemy? Try to use the newest one, because the 8.0 version of mysql has depreciated 'tx_isolation'.